# Aligning items to the bottom using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to use flex to align the items inside the parent to the bottom of parent, but it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#login {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 50px;
display: flex;
}
.login {
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px;
align-self: flex-end;
}
#loginButton {
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 7.5px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'login'>
<form method = 'POST' action = 'login.php'>
<input class = 'login' type = 'text' name = 'username' maxlength = '20' placeholder = 'Username' size = '10'>
<input class = 'login' type = 'password' name = 'password' maxlength = '20' placeholder = 'Password' size = '10'>
<input class = 'login' id = 'loginButton' type = 'submit' value = 'Login'>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your form:

```
form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Since only the *child elements* of a flex container become flex items, make the parent of the elements you wish to align a flex container.

In your code, `#login` was the flex container, making the `form` the only flex item. You need flex properties to apply one level deeper, so make `form` a flex container, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to align the items in the parent.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#login {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.login {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#loginButton {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id='login'>
  <form method='POST' action='login.php'>
    <input class='login' type='text' name='username' maxlength='20' placeholder='Username' size='10'>
    <input class='login' type='password' name='password' maxlength='20' placeholder='Password' size='10'>
    <input class='login' id='loginButton' type='submit' value='Login'>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: While the login button is aligned all the way at the bottom, the username and password is aligned slightly higher...Around 3 pixels off the bottom. Why is that?

Comment: Also, I tried this on my website, and it's not working for some reason. https://www.iscattered.com/testx.php

Comment: Well the items are different sizes...and you have different padding on the button.

Comment: And on your site the form has the buttons at the bottom but the form itself is not at the bottom of the wrapping div.

Answer (score 0):

`form` should be the flex container and `margin` can be used to finalize positioning and to avoid stretching.

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}
.login {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto 1em;
}
#loginButton {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7.5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
}
/* added for demo purpose to see the form in middle */

html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='login'>
  <form method='POST' action='login.php'>
    <input class='login' type='text' name='username' maxlength='20' placeholder='Username' size='10'>
    <input class='login' type='password' name='password' maxlength='20' placeholder='Password' size='10'>
    <input class='login' id='loginButton' type='submit' value='Login'>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: @jessica trying to use flex to align form elements, but none of those form elements where child of the flex box ... then align-self seems to show you wanted something at the far right ... margins in action to show you you can skip some flex properties and just use margins If question was not clear enough  or attempt of using flex was too clumsy, maybe rephrasing the question could help ?